# What is the difference between "app only" flow vs "delegated scenario" using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Please describe the difference. If user gives access to my app, then Can I use "delegated scenario" to act on behalf of a user and access his/her emails, contacts etc. I am already using MS Graph api to access my users' data but sometimes even after retrieving `access token` I encounter this message: `Resource could not be discovered.`

Answer (score 2):

Delegated Scopes are used for scenarios that involve an authenticated user. Unless you're building a daemon/service app or you have a very specific need, **it is a safe bet that you should be using Delegated Scopes**. Some scopes may still require Admin Consent (i.e. ability to read any users calendar) but the majority only require the User to consent themselves (i.e. ability to read their own calendar).

Application Scopes (aka "App Only") are used for scenarios where there is no user available to authenticate or the application is headless (and therefore no UI in which a user *could* authentication). These are extremely permissive permissions and *always* require a Global Administrator to consent to the scopes you've requested. These are also only applicable to Work/School Accounts (AAD) and cannot be used with personal Microsoft Accounts (MSA).

Which scopes are used is a direct result of the OAuth Grant you used to obtain the token.

- Authorization Code Grant (`authorization_code`) == Delegated scopes
- Implicit Grant (`implicit`) == Delegated scopes
- Client Credentials Grant (`client_credentials`) == Application scopes

Comment: Thanks Marc. I noticed that I'm using `authorization_code ` to get the token. But sometimes I encounter the message I described above. I thought maybe using an organizational account by my user caused that problem. But as you stated if I use `authorization_code ` then I should have access to his data even if their data is not stored on Microsoft. Right?

Comment: I don't follow. If their data isn't "on Microsoft", I'm not sure how you would expect to access that data via Microsoft Graph. Microsoft Graph is an aggregation of Microsoft service APIs (Office 365, Intune, Azure AD, etc.). I cannot traverse 3rd party systems today.

Comment: I am not sure if their data is stored somewhere else other than MS or not. The only thing I can see is when I use `authorization_code` for getting the token, and by using that token, for some users I hit `Resource could not be discovered` and dunno why?